Inclusion in a hereditary C*-subalgebra
Is my proof to the following correct? If correct, is there a way to simplify?

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra and $H\leq A$ a hereditary subalgebra. Then, for every $h\in H$, $h^*Ah\subset H$.

Attempted proof.
For every Hermitian element $s\in A_{sa}$, we have $0\leq s+\|s\|\leq 2\|s\|$, which gives, for $h\in H$, $0\leq h^* (s+\|s\|)h\leq 2\|s\|h^*h\in H$. Hence $h^*sh=h^*(s+\|s\|)h-\|s\|h^*h$ is a linear combination of two elements in $H$. Thus, $h^*A_{sa}h\subset H$.
Therefore, for every $a\in A$, since $a=\text{Re}(a)+i\text{Im}(a)$, where $\text{Re}(a), \text{Im}(a)\in A_{sa}$, we have $h^*ah\in H$, since it is a $\mathbb{C}$-linear combination of elements in $h^*A_{sa}h\subset H$. $\square$
Thanks a lot.

This works, but I think the argument becomes clearer if you just consider a positive element $s \in A$, and use that since $$0 \leq s \leq \lVert s \rVert 1_A \implies 0 \leq h^* s h \leq \lVert s \rVert h^* h \in H.$$ Since any element of $a$ is a linear combination of at most four positive elements, the proof is complete.

Thanks! That does simplify it.
